# How do I create a Q-Q plot with Gamma distribution?

Tags: r

I have continuous data that I determined had a gamma distribution. The key data are here:

```
data <- data.frame(yr = c("2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"),
avg_ctax = c(5.0273, 12.5205, 17.5205, 22.5205, 27.5137, 30, 30, 30),
mt_co2e = c(156.3976, 148.8853, 148.2108, 150.5952, 153.5574, 155.3867, 154.5265, 152.0863))
```

I then made a generalized linear model to analyze the data, one without transformation:

```
g_data <- glm(mt_co2e ~ avg_ctax, family = Gamma, data = data)
```

And one with ln-transformation:

```
g_data_log <- glm(mt_co2e ~ avg_ctax, family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = data)
```

Now, I need to make a Q-Q plot for gamma-distributed values to evaluate goodness of fit. How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw a QQ plot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092506/how-to-draw-a-qq-plot-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to make a QQ-plot for the residuals of your model.
If so, this is done with `qqnorm` and then `qqline`.

```
data <- data.frame(yr = c("2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"),
                   avg_ctax = c(5.0273, 12.5205, 17.5205, 22.5205, 27.5137, 30, 30, 30),
                   mt_co2e = c(156.3976, 148.8853, 148.2108, 150.5952, 153.5574, 155.3867, 154.5265, 152.0863))
g_data <- glm(mt_co2e ~ avg_ctax, family = Gamma, data = data)
g_data_log <- glm(mt_co2e ~ avg_ctax, family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = data)


qqnorm(resid(g_data_log)) 
qqline(resid(g_data_log))
```

[image]